# Display a single SQL columns into multiple columns of an HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html

Is this possible to display a single SQL column into multiple columns of an HTML table in the same row ?

In this example, a table in MySQL has one column (Col1). I want to display these data in a single ROW but in 3 columns one beside one, so i want to display these data 3 columns under 3 columns to the final result, is there a way to do that ?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('domain', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$sql = "select * from table1";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
$col1 = $row['col1'];

echo "<td> $col1 </td>";
echo "<td> $col1 </td>";
echo "<td> $col1 </td>"; //The problem here that these data will repeat because we put the same variable in 3 TD and i want my data doesn't repeat.

}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: So you want a single SQL ROW and all of its columns to be displayed in a  HTML table right?  I think you're mixing the terms ROW and COLUMN.  2nd your while loop will repeat for each row so you're writing out a whole table each time which seems odd.  wouldn't you just want to write out each row within the while loop and open/close each row within the loop but let the table exist outside the loop?

Comment: I just want that the data of my SQL columns will display in 3 columns one beside one , not one under one, like if i have 3 SQL columns and i want to display them in my table

Comment: Yep I don't understand the question then.  PRovide example sample data in the database table, and the expected output on your HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There:

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('domain', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $sql = "select * from table1";
    $sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    $pos = 0;
    $results_per_row = 3; #you can change it to a different value
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)){
        $pos++;
        $col1 = $row['col1'];
        echo "<td> $col1 </td>";
        if($pos % $results_per_row == 0) 
            echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    // fill the last row with empty fields, if it has less than
    // $results_per_row values, to keep the proper table syntax
    while($pos % $results_per_row != 0){
        $pos++;
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I don't know how can say you : thank you, you are only the one understand what i want thank you so much brother,  but i don't know why the while loop stay loading in the browser but when i cut your second while it worked  perfectly.

Comment: At first I forgot to increase `$pos` in it, the final version should be ok.

Comment: Very clear answer now it's OK, thank you.. you are great

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on comment: 
Move the table and tr tags outside of the loop.

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('domain', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $sql = "select * from table1";
    $sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    echo "<table><tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
        $col1 = $row['col1'];
        echo "<td> $col1 </td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

Previous Reply

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for but I think your concern is that you are repeating multiple tables and outputting one value??

If so, you should move the tags for the opening and ending of the table outside of the loop and then for each cell, echo the actual value you want for that cell.

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('domain', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $sql = "select * from table1";
    $sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Col 1 Header Name</th><th>Col 2 Header Name</th><th>Col 3 Header Name</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> $row['col1'] </td>";
        echo "<td> $row['col2'] </td>";
        echo "<td> $row['col3'] </td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank, but you didn't understand me, i have only one SQL columns in my table database and i want to display its values in one TR, when i put my variable in my TD the result appears one under one, but me i want that these values will appear one beside one, 3 cells under 3 cells to the final result

Comment: I edited my response to move the tr tag outside of the loop with the table tag and to account for only one result col.  Does that meet your needs or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: @1.5millionschahiddjazeyri check out my answer

Comment: Ok I see now, I think @FlashThunder has it.